# Plot data from SparkR DataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, avro, sparkr

I have an avro file which I am reading as follows:

```
avroFile <-read.df(sqlContext, "avro", "com.databricks.spark.avro")
```

This file as lat/lon columns but I am not able to plot them like a regular dataframe.
Neither am I able to access the column using the '$' operator.

ex.

```
avroFile$latitude
```

Any help regarding avro files and operation on them using R are appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `ggplot2` for plotting, try ggplot2.SparkR. This package allows you to take SparkR `DataFrame` directly as input for `ggplot()` function call.

https://github.com/SKKU-SKT/ggplot2.SparkR

Comment: Like @smishra said, the latest version ggplot2.sparkR supports is SparkR 1.6.2  as mentioned in this document https://github.com/SKKU-SKT/ggplot2.SparkR/blob/master/DESCRIPTION

Answer (score 4):

And you won't be able to plot it directly. SparkR `DataFrame` is not compatible with functions which expect `data.frame` as an input. This is not even a data structure in a strict sense but simply a recipe how to process input data. It is materialized only when you execute an action.

If you want to plot it you'll have `collect` it first.. Beware that it fetches all the data the local machine so typically it is something you want to avoid on full data set.

Answer (score 3):

As zero323 mentioned, you cannot currently run R visualizations on distributed SparkR DataFrames. You can run them on local data.frames. Here is one way you could make a new dataframe with just the columns you want to plot, and then collect a random sample of them to a local data.frame which you can plot from

```
latlong <- (avroFile, avroFile$latitude, avrofile$longitude)
latlongsample <- collect(sample(latlong, FALSE, .1))
plot(latlongsample)
```

the signature for sample method is:
sample(x, withReplacement, fraction, seed)